# How do I update the UI during an event using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

I'm a bit stuck with a problem. I feel like the solution should be fairly straight forward but I'm completely out of ideas for some reason.

Here's the problem. I've got a user control with a couple of buttons. Think of them as 'On' and 'Off'. When either button is clicked an async method is called. If the method is successful an event is fired. Within the event I want to update the enabled property of the two buttons so that only a single button is clickable at any one time. The problem is that any changes I make to the properties are not shown on screen because the postback is already complete. I tried wrapping the buttons in an UpdatePanel but I get an "Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'xxxx' before Render' error. I understand why the problem occurs but I can't think of a solution. Help!

Ideally what I'd like to do is simply call a method within the event that will update the UI, but I don't know if that's possible.

EDIT

Here's some example code. I can't post the exact code, but this explains the problem:

```
Partial Class ExampleUserControl
    Inherits Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Private WithEvents obj As MyObj

    Private Sub btnOn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOn.Click
        obj = New MyObj()
        obj.On() ' Calls OnEvent on success
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOff_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOff.Click
        obj = New MyObj()
        obj.Off() ' Calls OffEvent on success
    End Sub

    Private Sub On() Handles obj.OnEvent
        btnOn.Enabled = False
        btnOff.Enabled = True
        'updatePanel.Update() This throws an exception
    End Sub

    Private Sub Off() Handles obj.OffEvent
        btnOn.Enabled = True
        btnOff.Enabled = False
        'updatePanel.Update() This throws an exception
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what is exactly going on without code...

Comment: I agree with Brian, but my first thoughts are that with it being async an UpdatePanel should work, and seeing your code may shed some light as to why it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just "push" html to the browser, updatepanel or not. You can only react to a "pull" from the browser.

So you need to have the update panel refresh itself every *x* seconds. **Then** you can check the server side status and update the panel accordingly.

See for instance: http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/

Don't forget to switch off the timer when the action is done.

Comment: This solution works for me. It was pretty easy to set up a timer as you suggested. Potentially some Javascript calling a web service method would be more efficient, but I'm more than happy to get my code working this way!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, otherwise I would, so I'll just ask my question here.  Have you tried putting the enabling logic directly in the btnOn_Click event handler and adding btnOn as a trigger to the updatepanel?  My concern is that the secondary event is not a trigger on the UpdatePanel, so the update event is not looking for that event.

Like this:

```
 Private Sub btnOn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOn.Click
        btnOn.Enabled = False
        btnOff.Enabled = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I could, but it wouldn't reflect what happening. For example if a user clicks the On button and the OnEvent is NOT called, then something has gone wrong and I don't want to disable the On button and enable the Off button

Comment: You could put an 'if' statement around it and only change the control state if everything worked properly.

Comment: I'm afraid not because the OnEvent would be fired after the onclick event

Answer (score 0):

Solve this with an UpdatePanel.

Make your AsyncPostBackTrigger's for you buttons.  Based on your logic on the code behind enable or disable them accordingly.

Alternatively, register a client script from the server side.